# rpc call "personal_signAndSendTransaction/eth_sendTransaction" sending tokens but losing ether 3 hours later

Tags: go-ethereum

Using rpc call personal_signAndSendTransaction/eth_sendTransaction to send token on Ropsten testnet. 
Tokens were received but extra ether were charged and 0.19958 ether were taken from the sending address for three times and all send to an address:
0xbc3edbdfe92dfe06bc005d499b2a35649baec237

The only difference for personal_signAndSendTransaction and eth_sendTransaction is that when using eth_sendTransaction, all ethers in the address will be gone.
Not sure if anyone has similar experience but that seems to be a very serious issue.

System information

Geth version: `geth version`

> Version: 1.8.1-stable

OS & Version: Windows/Linux/OSX
Linux
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
Release:        16.04
Codename:       xenial

Go Version: go1.9.4

Commit hash : (if `develop`)
Git Commit: 1e67410e88d2685bc54611a7c9f75c327b553ccc

Expected behaviour

1. Geth connect to testnet Ropsten and all addresses, contract, and transactions are on Ropsten.
2. sending tokens to my wallet address using following RPC call.
   **RPC call:** personal_signAndSendTransaction
   Token Transaction received by the destination account.                       OK

Actual behaviour

The expected token transactions was sent but three hours later, three ether transactions occurred and a total of 3x0.19958 ethers were take away from the address: 0x2f6e4dd0286aacdbfa88db0e92cc7a1c89709175.

0x7c6121679ddeae6aa42759acbf4a8032560438440f69a1103d983e3110c90941 | 2882698 | 8 hrs 58 mins ago | 0x2f6e4dd0286aacdbfa88db0e92cc7a1c89709175 | OUT | 0xbc3edbdfe92dfe06bc005d499b2a35649baec237 | 0.19958 Ether | 0.00042
-- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | -- | --
0x342b729dbf7763aff4d606cf4f2f99e10dda6910a876136753bd27975e13ad8b | 2882698 | 8 hrs 58 mins ago | 0x2f6e4dd0286aacdbfa88db0e92cc7a1c89709175 | OUT | 0xbc3edbdfe92dfe06bc005d499b2a35649baec237 | 0.19958 Ether | 0.00042
0x38fde4291f48fac9bcf42a79570f04b7841f2cb58a01d8148e9dbf13e434c08f | 2882698 | 8 hrs 58 mins ago | 0x2f6e4dd0286aacdbfa88db0e92cc7a1c89709175 | OUT | 0xbc3edbdfe92dfe06bc005d499b2a35649baec237 | 0.19958 Ether | 0.00042

Steps to reproduce the behaviour

{
    "jsonrpc":"2.0",
    "method":"personal_signAndSendTransaction",
    "params":[
        {
            "from": "0x2f6e4dd0286aacdbfa88db0e92cc7a1c89709175",
            "to": "0x567527C374602B9d206DDfaf001dECA3F595b7b5",
            "gasLimit" : "0xcc40",
            "value": "0x0",
            "data": "0xa9059cbb0000000000000000000000005fec1b24b198ecf5feb9e44ec79314594225c85300000000000000000000000000000000000000000000021e27c1806e59a40000"
        },
            "bitontop123"
    ],
    "id":1
}

TxHash:
0xb6f795f717fd5f95c2c4157802c9946e68c6c2caa61a83aee280d20f634e3646 
TxReceipt Status:   Success
Block Height:          2881961 (3846 block confirmations)
TimeStamp:            11 hrs 59 mins ago (Mar-22-2018 05:15:55 AM +UTC)
From:                     0x2f6e4dd0286aacdbfa88db0e92cc7a1c89709175
To:                         Contract 0x567527c374602b9d206ddfaf001deca3f595b7b5
Token Transfer:      10,001 ERC20 (TESTOKEN)  from 0x2f6e4dd0286aacdbfa88db0e92cc7a1c89709175to  0x5fec1b24b198ecf5feb9e44ec79314594225c853
Value:                     0 Ether ($0.00) 
Gas Limit:               90000 
Gas Used By Txn:   38036 
Gas Price:               0.00000002 Ether (20 Gwei) 
Actual Tx Cost/Fee:              0.00076072 Ether ($0.000000) 
Nonce:                   1436 
InputData:              Function: transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) ***
                               MethodID: 0xa9059cbb
                               [0]:  0000000000000000000000005fec1b24b198ecf5feb9e44ec79314594225c853

## [1]:  00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000021e27c1806e59a40000

Backtrace

`[backtrace]`